# Tauri appWindow not listening to webview emit event

Tags: tauri

I've got this basic React component I'm loading into tauri.

```js
import { WebviewWindow, appWindow } from "@tauri-apps/api/window";

console.log(`setting up listener`);
appWindow.listen("my-event", function (f) {
  //this is not getting hit...
  console.log(`event hit!:`, f);
});

render(<button onClick={()=>{
            const webview = new WebviewWindow("newWindow", {
              url: "index.html",
              title: "newWindow"
            });

            setTimeout(async () => {
              console.log(`fire my-event`)
              webview.emit("my-event", "jjjjjj");
            }, 5000);

}} />, document.querySelector("#demo"));
```

I open up two windows (both with the same code above running in them), and then hit the button in one of them.
Here's a screenshot of the two windows devtoools showing what is happening:

[image: listener not getting hit]

Any idea why the "my-event" listener is not getting hit (by either window)? Am I misunderstanding how the event passing system is supposed to work?

Is the `appWindow` somehow different from the webview returned from `new WebviewWindow("newWindow")` call?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to listen global events described [in this doc](https://tauri.app/v1/guides/features/events#global-events)
`listen` is for global events and `appWindow` listening is limited to only current window.

**For global events**,

```js
import { emit, listen } from '@tauri-apps/api/event'

// listen to the `click` event and get a function to remove the event listener
// there's also a `once` function that subscribes to an event and automatically unsubscribes the listener on the first event
const unlisten = await listen('click', (event) => {
  // event.event is the event name (useful if you want to use a single callback fn for multiple event types)
  // event.payload is the payload object
})

// emits the `click` event with the object payload
emit('click', {
  theMessage: 'Tauri is awesome!',
})
```

**For current window**,

```js
import { appWindow, WebviewWindow } from '@tauri-apps/api/window'

// emit an event that is only visible to the current window
appWindow.emit('event', { message: 'Tauri is awesome!' })

// create a new webview window and emit an event only to that window
const webview = new WebviewWindow('window')
webview.emit('event')
```

Comment: thanks for responding but I don't see why the appWindow event above wouldn't be logged by at least one of the windows I have open above?